# Match text before specific text in nongreedy fashion with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have text of the form

`<span style="color:red;">hello</span> <span style="color:green;">world</span>`

I want to try and match one of the `span` tags based on either the `hello` or the `world` text. I've tried something of the form:

`(<span.*?)(?=world).*?<\/span>`

using lookahead, but that matches the entire string rather than just the `<span style="color:green;">world</span>` I was looking for. How can I match the `<span...` text before `world` in a non-greedy fashion?

Comment: What language/tool are you using with your regex?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Python `re` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
(<span[^>]*>)world.*?<\/span>
```

Here is a Python snippet with this regex in action:

```
input = "<span style=\"color:red;\">hello</span> <span style=\"color:green;\">world</span>"

matchObj = re.match( r'.*(<span[^>]*>)world.*?</span>.*', input, re.M|re.I)

if matchObj:
    print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
    print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Note that in the Python code I had to add `.*` to the start and end of the original pattern, because it seems that the Python regex engine insists on matching the pattern against the entire string.  There might be a flag for avoiding this, but in any case hopefully this answer gets you unstuck and allows you to continue your work.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Can you explain what the `[^>]` is doing? Or the name of that concept?

Comment: `[^>]` just means any character which is _not_ a closing bracket.  This is how I got around the problem you were having.  Check this [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjeRRB/1) where it seems to be working.  I'm working on a Python demo right now, hope to have that up in a few minutes.

Comment: I see how this works. Wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks, I learned something new!